# How to refresh the fragment onResume

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-recyclerview

I am a newbie in Android development. I am facing an issue. I need some help from you guys.

Firstly, I am working on an application that is similar to BookMyShow.

I have an activity that contains a fragment. The activity contains a list of timeslots in a recycler view.

When I click on one of the timeslots, I go to new activity where I book the show with the specific details like username, id, timeslot_selected, etc and once he submits the "SUBMIT" button in the activity, it should come back to the same fragment that he was in, earlier, and show his details on the fragment. Initial there is nobody in the recycler view, now the user should see himself in that recycler view at the selected timeSlot as an icon.

I have the next button as well. When the user clicks on it, I am replacing the fragment with the following date. If the user clicks on one of the slots, he would be redirected to the same booking activity and once he submits, he should come back to the previous fragment with the same date that he was on earlier and with an updated icon of himself.

Now, I am unable to show that updated icon in the previous fragment once he clicks submit on the booking activity. Can you please suggest what should I do?

I tried detaching and attaching the fragment but to no avail. Please help me with a solution. Thanks in Advance!

SampleActivity.java:

```
public class SampleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;
Person person;
String id, name, date;


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sample);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    id = intent.getStringExtra("id");
    name= intent.getStringExtra("name");
    date= intent.getStringExtra("date");
    person= (Person) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("person");


    text= findViewById(R.id.name);
    text.setText(name);

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("id", id);
    bundle.putString("name", name);
    bundle.putString("date", date);
    bundle.putSerializable("Person", person);

    FragmentA newFragment = new FragmentA();
    newFragment.setArguments(bundle);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.mainFrameLayout, newFragment, "main_fragment").commit();

}
```

FragmentA.java:

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

RecyclerView recyclerView;

public FragmentA() {
}

@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_new, container, false);

    recyclerView = view.findViewById(R.id.slots);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

    requestQueue = VolleySingleton.getmInstance(getActivity()).getRequestQueue();
    newList = new ArrayList<>();


    next = view.findViewById(R.id.nextButton);
    timeView = view.findViewById(R.id.timeOn);
    dateText= view.findViewById(R.id.date);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();
    assert bundle != null;
    id= bundle.getString("id");
    name = bundle.getString("name");
    date = bundle.getString("date");
    person = (Person) bundle.getSerializable("Person");

    next.setOnClickListener(this);


        return view;
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if (v.getId()== R.id.nextButton) {
        replaceFragment();
    }

}



private void replaceFragment() {

    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
  bundle.putString("id", id);
  bundle.putString("name", name);
  bundle.putString("date", date);
  bundle.putSerializable("Person", person);
   bundle.putSerializable("hashmap", (Serializable) hashmap);

    fm = requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    f = new FragmentFirst();
    f.setArguments(bundle);
    ft.replace(R.id.fragmentLayout, f, "main_fragment");
    ft.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();


}

@Override
public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}



public void refreshData() {

    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    Fragment currentFragment = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("main_fragment");
    FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    if(currentFragment != null) {
        fragmentTransaction.detach(currentFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.attach(currentFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: use onAttach method

Answer (score 0):

As I see you are trying to go to a new instance of FragmentA in your booking activity. If you want to send data to an activity, process the data and return the result, in your case you could do it by starting new activity for result by `startForActivityResult` and also set the result before finish the activity with `setResult` method in your booking activity. In this case you can use the result via `onActivityResult` method. But I suggest you to use fragment for the booking process as well instead of activity.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I did exactly what you said earlier like using the setResult method and was getting the correct output. However, for the nested fragments it is not coming. I mean only for FragmentA it is coming. For the following fragments, it is not updating. Any idea, what do I need to change.

Comment: If you want to have the result in another fragment that does not exist in the stack right now, you can pass hold and pass the data that you recieved in fragmentA. But in this case that the fragmentB for example is alive, you can get the result in it's onActivityResult method directly. I hope I could help. But if you had any problem with it, you can send me a piece of your source code that I can help to correct it more easier.